# Criar Menu DropDown

Tags: html, css, menu, dropdown

Alguém me poderia ajudar? Gostava de tornar este menu num menu dropdown, mas ainda não tenho conhecimentos para tal, e gostava de pedir ajuda.

// CSS

```
nav#mainnav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav#mainnav li {
    padding:0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #99C581;
    border-top: 1px solid #6FAB4F;
}

nav#mainnav li.selected-item  {
    border-bottom:none;
}

nav#mainnav li.selected-item a,
nav#mainnav li.selected-item a:hover {
    color:#80B763;
    font-weight:bold;
    background: #fff;
}

nav#mainnav li a:hover {
    background:#669D48;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav#mainnav li a {
    color: #f0f0f0;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 17px;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight:  bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

// HTML

```
<nav id="mainnav">
  <ul>
    <li class="selected-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Exemplo 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Exemplo 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Exemplo 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Exemplo 4</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Veja no site [Dinamic Drive](http://dynamicdrive.com/). Lá possui muitas coisa pronta, e que é possível customizar.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

Answer (score 1):

Você pode começar alterando a estrutura HTML do seu menu, não que não seja possível fazer com essa estrutura, mas seria melhor trabalhar de forma diferente. 
Este é só um exemplo e você precisa fazer as modificações de acordo com suas necessidades

```css
#mainnav ul{
  list-style: none;
}

#mainnav ul li{
  padding:10px 15px;
  background:#000000;
}

.wrapper-menu{
  position:relative;
}

.dropdown{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  display:none;
}


.wrapper-dropdown:hover > .dropdown{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="mainnav">
  <ul class="wrapper-menu">
    <li class="wrapper-dropdown">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Exemplo 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Exemplo 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Exemplo 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Exemplo 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Esta estrutura HTML para dropdown pode abrigar vários dropdowns, com essa estrutura que você usa atualmente você só poderia colocar algumas poucas opções

Answer (score 0):

@Renan voçê perguntou sobre o css??

Vou tentar explicar de uma forma detalhada:

Primeiro vc deve perceber que o seu codigo esta dentro de uma nav, ok vc disse para o navegador semanticamente que aqui dentro do nav será a sua sessão de navegação ok, logo em seguida vc colocou uma ul e dentro dessa ul, vc colocou 5 li(s);

Explicando como vc poderia estilizar isso no css;

Tenha em mente que vc começa a estilizar a ul pai,

```
ul.menu {
      list-style:none; //Repara, quero remover as bolinhas das li(s)
}
```

agora vc iriá estiliza os seus links;

```
/*Configura todos os links do menu*/
ul.menu a {
      text-decoration:none; //Quero remover o sublinhado da linha
      color: #fff; //cor do link
      display:block; //faz com que o elemento HTML seja renderizado como bloco, aqui acontece a magica;
}


/*Faz os <li>s ficarem na horizontal*/
 ul.menu > li {
       //Perceba que não quero estilizar todas as lis, somente as que são filhos direto da minha ul pai;
       //Quero que as li(s) ficam deitadas ex:Home Contact  AboutMe  etc
       float:left; //irão flutuar a esquerda
       position:relative; //A posição relativa ao pai
 }
```

[Explicação sobre Posicionamento relativo e absoluto do css](http://pt-br.learnlayout.com/position.html)

```
/*Configurar os links do menu principal*/
ul.menu > li > a {
     position: relative;
     padding: 20px;
     margin: 0 5px;
}

/*Configurar o efeito ao clicar o mouse no link*/
ul.menu > li > a:active{
    top: 3px;
    left: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px -2px 0px #009900;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

/*Configurar o fundo do menu principal quando o mause passar em cima do meu link*/
ul.menu > li > a:hover{
    background: #009900;
}
```

Se tivesse dentro das suas li(s) outra ul:

```
/*Mostrar o submenu no evento do mouse hover*/
ul.menu > li:hover > ul.submenu{
    display: block;
}
```

O restante das configurações do sub-menu é parecido, ate aqui se vc entendeu o codigo, ficará facil de vc ter a logica de como construir um menu drop down, fica ligado que existe centenas maneiras de fazer isso, o interessante seria vc tentar entender o seletor, as propriedades, valores e a forma de se declarar os mesmos, como funciona a hierarquia do css não é facil no inicio ficar fera nisso, mas a pratica leva a perfeição.
Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
o Bootstrap veio para facilitar de vez a nossa vida com o css. ele padroniza toda a estrutura css e tem [nesse site](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp) tem uma documentação com tudo quase pronto! :)

Simplesmente associe um as três Tags no Head referenciando o css, a biblioteca jQuery e a versão compilada, os três nesta ordem:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

<!--Obedeça esta estrutura de diretório, primeiramente o Bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- A Biblioteca jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- O Javascript compilado -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Seu Site</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Página 1
        <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Página 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Página 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Página 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Página 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Página 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```